# Spherical Mercator - World bounds

Tags: coordinate-system, fme-form, extents

What are the correct world bounds in the Spherical Mercator projection (EPSG:3857 and EPSG:900913)

In some source I got those bounds [see this link in the maxExtent parameter](http://trac.osgeo.org/openlayers/wiki/SphericalMercator):

```
minx: -20037508.3427892
miny: -20037508.3427892
maxx: 20037508.3427892
maxy: 20037508.3427892
```

However in FME, I got those bounds:

```
minx: -40075016.6855785
miny: -20037508.3427892
maxx: 40075016.6855785
maxy: 20037508.3427892
```

Comment: Mathematically, there are no bounds to the x coordinate. What, then, would "correct" mean to you?

Comment: Ok, I need to set this for an OpenLayers app but I would be curious to understand why they double the x coordinate in FME

Comment: I couldn't tell you about FME specifically--probably only their developers could answer that.

Comment: Why would you quote world coordinates to sub-micron level of precision?

Comment: Thats how those sources are defining the world extent in spherical mercator

Comment: I have the same question, but I'm thinking of "correct" in terms of 1 world.  aka the bounds of a single world without any wrapping.  The limits would be something like -180, -85.06, 180, 85.06.

Comment: @MarcelWilson your bounds are in degrees for a lat/lon projection, in spherical mercator, units are in meters

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The bounds for EPSG 3857 are:

```
xmin: -PI * 6378137,
ymin: -PI * 6378137,
xmax:  PI * 6378137,
ymax:  PI * 6378137
```

which result in the following bounds:

```
xmin: -20037508.3427892,
ymin: -20037508.3427892,
xmax: 20037508.3427892,
ymax: 20037508.3427892
```

*Source: https://epsg.io/3857*

- The extent is a square. And, the unit is in SI meter.
- OpenLayer sets this bound for you by default when you work with a data source that is in EPSG 3857.
- If you regularly perform (sizeable) map caching or map tile generation - knowing where the bounds are lets you have fine control over the tools you use, and thus planning, monitoring, concurrent/parallel generations, and etc.
- If you write codes that convert coordinates to map tile indexes and vice-versa - you need to know where the bounds are.
- However, do note that the valid geodetic bounds (i.e., latitude and longitude) that can be projected into EPSG 3857 are [xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax] = [-180, -85.06, 180, 85.06].